# Unable to access the some properties in Json

Tags: json, react-native

I ran a api and get the json object of object. Below is the screenshot of that object. In react native, I am getting this data in component from redux with the key "data".
[image]

When I try to fetch city name in mapStateToProps component, I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> Blockquote

my mapStateToProps is below.

```js
const mapStateToProp = ({data}) => {
  //console.log(data);
  return {
    city: data.data.city.name 
  }
}
```

I am getting complete data to city but unable to access its name property Why?

Comment: I think you need to do data.city.name

Comment: can you please provide console.log result of exact data

Comment: @Priya I tried that for a whole day but at last I found data.data.city is giving me the complete data not data.city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting the data from a fetch request the city property probably doesn't exist before the request. Try preventing the error by checking if the city exists when you set the value in mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProp = ({data}) => {
  //console.log(data);
  return {
    city: data.data.city ? data.data.city.name : null 
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that it is also a good practice to not have deeply nested data in your store.